# Save selected column in excel using Macro in 1 page

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save the label from excel using Macro with column a , column b and column c as shown below in 1 page.
Below is the Macro that preview only 1 column in pdf.

```
 Sub Save_PDF()
  Dim Nm As String
  Dim Rng As Range

 Set Rng = Range("B2")

Nm = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Nm = Left(Nm, InStrRev(Nm, ".") - 1) & Format(Now, " yyyymmddhhmmss") & 
".pdf"

Rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Nm, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Example of the Label that I needed 
[image: Example of the Label]

Example of column in excel

[[image: Example of column in excel[2]]

Thanks for help

Comment: If you want all 3 columns then why export only B2?

Comment: @TimWilliams tested Set Rng = Range("A2:B2") but the output is not in a single page

Comment: Can you please explain your question in a lot more detail? Is your issue trying to arrange the columns as per your diagram? Are you trying to get the values "A" and "228" also displaying in the output? Are you trying to get all rows on one page, or all rows each on a separate page, or are you trying to print only one row and having problems getting it all onto just one page?

Comment: @Michael Hi, right now I'm trying to print 1 page only for the first row and having problem cant get all onto just one page.

Comment: I'm still confused. Your first screenshot example, is that all you want to print, the barcode from column B?  So you just need to widen it for printing, no?

Comment: @BruceWayne ya, the first screenshot example is what I need, but right now if I add the Range("A2:B2") the output is A2 1 page and B2 at second page.

Comment: Look into how to set page breaks. That could also be quickly found using the macro recorder. Turn it on, set the page break to all one page, and see what you get.  Edit: Or just see @Michael's answer :P

Answer (score 2):

To force everything to print on one page:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .ResetAllPageBreaks
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the input on this I really appreciate it

Comment: But after added the ResetAllPageBreaks the result still the same 2 page, the Range I Set Rng = Range("A2:B2").

Comment: What happens if you select A2:B2 and then print the selected range?

Comment: I try using Range("A2,B2").Select but the output still same.